# How can I implement a refresh function for a data stream?

Tags: angular, typescript, rxjs

I want to implement a refresh function to update the current list `items$` while simultaneously being able to await the `refreshItems()`.

This is my current implementation that works:

```
private readStream = new Subject<T[]>();
readStream$ = this.readStream.asObservable();

getItems = (): Observable<T[]> => 
  this.get().pipe(tap((res) => this.readStream.next(res)));

items$ = merge(this.getItems(), this.readStream$).pipe(
  distinctUntilChanged(),
  share({ connector: () => new ReplaySubject(1) })
);

refreshItems = () => this.getItems();
```

As you might have noticed, `items$` will start off with calling `this.getItems()`, but this also triggers the `this.readStream$` later on, hence the `distinctUntilChanged()`.

I want to be able to call `refreshItems()` from another location, and at the same time I want to be able to know when the call completes, which is possible now when I use `refreshItems()` in a higher-order mapping function. I did it this way because`items$` has a `ReplaySubject` for caching purposes. I'll get the previous value when I listen to `items$`.

Currently, I'm using `merge(this.getItems(), this.readStream$)` because I want to get the items immediately when the object gets created, but also want to 'update' it when the `getItems()` get executed.

Is there a way to implement it without `distinctUntilChanged()` or make it better suitable for extension and/or cleaner?

**Edit**: The following explains the reason behind the `refreshItems()`: I have two classes that contain each other (eg. `Class A` contains zero or more IDs of `Class B` and `Class B` contains an ID of `Class A` (one-to-many relationship)). When `Class A` gets created, one or more IDs of `Class B` gets assigned to it as well. I need a fresh list of `Class B` when `Class A` is created to update the UI (only show non-assigned classes). That's why I have to wait until the `refreshItems()` of `Class B` is completed. Because `refreshItems()` gets called when the creation of `Class A` is completed.

**Edit 2**: Changing the code of `items$` to using `skip()` works as well:

```
items$ = merge(this.getItems().pipe(skip(1)), this.readStream$)
    .pipe(share({ connector: () => new ReplaySubject(1) }));
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe: have one subject triggering the `get`, and serve the data stream in two flavors, shared (for generic consumer) and "raw" (for callers of `refreshItems()`).

```
sharedReadStream$: Observable<T>;
private _readStream$: Observable<T>;
private _refresher$: Subject<void> = new Subject();

constructor() {
    this._readStream$ = this._refresher$.pipe(switchMap(() => this.get()));
    this.sharedReadStream$ = this.readStream$.pipe(share());
    this.refreshItems();
}

refreshItems = () => {
    this._refresher$.next();
    return this._readStream$;
}
```

Comment: By doing this I wouldn't be able to 'wait' for the `refreshItems()` to complete, which I need in another part of my application.

Comment: @Starfish sure you can, `readStream$` still won't emit until `get()` emits.

Comment: How would that work? In another component I'm listening to the `refreshItems()` like this: `someObservable.pipe(switchMap(_ => this.itemService.refreshItems()), *some operations*);`

Comment: maybe replace share with shareReplay(1)

Comment: @Starfish OK, looks like I misunderstood your use case. Sorry for that. I edited my answer.